# Dart: Cast List<dynamic> to List<DocumentReference>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I everyone!
I'm just triyng to cast a List<**dynamic**> to List<**DocumentReference**> .That's my code:

```
UserM.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    //_id = map['id'];
    //_name = map['name'];
    //_imgsrc = map['imgsrc'];
    //_adresse = Adresse.fromMap(map['adresse'] as Map<String, dynamic>);
    var test = map['restoFavs'];
    _restoFavs = new List<DocumentReference>.from(test);
    //_panier = map['panier'];
    //_email = map['email'];
  }
```

But i have this error on screen:
[image]
The map come from firestore document data.I use flutter 1.22.5 dart 2.5.2
Can someone help me, please!

Comment: What do you get if you log the `test` variable?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
_restoFavs = [for(var e in test.values) e as DocumentReference];
```

Comment: not at all:  No suchMethodError: Class List<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'values'. Receiver: Instance(Length:0) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling :values

Comment: then try without the `.values`